# How to ask a former advisor to resume 'contact'?

Tags: graduate-school, advisor, germany, networking, netherlands

A few years ago, I completed by bachelor's by creating a 'bachelor's thesis'. My advisor for this thesis. The thesis went very well, I've got a high grade and my advisor was very much impressed by my work (for an undergrad, at least) during and after the project.

However, he left almost immediately after that. I do think he left amicably, he even showed up briefly during his former course and I believe that some other university simply gave him more opportunity to do what he wants.

That was the last time I spoke with him. A lot has happened since and I'm thinking of perhaps contacting him to do a PhD in his expertise, although I'm not certain.

I do wonder how I should re-initiate contact. I have much to tell and ask, but long mails may be unread for long. I think meeting 'in the flesh' is unlikely to be possible (he isn't exactly far away, but still in a different country)

If this is useful, I am Dutch, the university is in the Netherlands, the advisor has a Germanic mother-tongue and is now in Germany. (I think)

Answer (score 5):

Send him a short email reminding him who you are amd ask if he is planning on taking a PhD student soon. Let the conversation develop from there.

Comment: Even better, if he works in Germany, there is a good chance that he will be able to offer PhD scholarships (actually: jobs) directly, without going through a central admission system.